# Is this cron correct using multiple ranges?

Tags: linux, cron

Is this the right way to run process.sh **every minute** from 11:01-11:27 and from 11:32-11:59 ?

```
1-27/1,32-59/1 11 * * * process.sh
```

Comment: http://www.cronchecker.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have multiple ranges in one statement. You can either set it like

```
 1,2,3,4,...27,32,33...
```

or, to have it better readable, split it up to two statements

```
1-27 11 * * * process.sh
32-59 11 * * * ... process.sh
```

If you don't need cron to log or output something, consider to add

```
1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to the end.

Comment: Also an option: run the script every minute but have the script do nothing on minutes 28 through 31.